# How to access column in parent table based on foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am using MVC and these are the tables:

**Table: Parent**
`Columns`
ParentID
ParentName

**Table: Child**
`Columns`
ChildID
ParentID

There is relationship between both tables using `ParentID`. I am using following code to display `ParentName` value but getting error.

`.cshtml`

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(
    settings =>
    {
        settings.Columns.Add("ChildID");
        settings.Columns.Add("ParentName");
    }).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

`.cs`

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var Childs = db.Child.Include(a => a.Parent);
            return View(Childs.ToList());
        }
```

`Error`

> A field or property with name 'ParentName' was not found in the
> selected data source. Possible causes of this error may be the
> following: an incorrect or case-insensitive spelling of the grid
> column name; assigning a wrong or not properly initialized data source
> to the grid.

How do I access `ParentName` column which is in parent table?

Answer (score -1):

I found solution and it was very simple.

**Change following line**
`settings.Columns.Add("ParentName");`

**To this line**
`settings.Columns.Add("Parent.ParentName");`